# Apereo CAS 5.0.x Installation : No web.xml in the overlay

Tags: spring, tomcat, single-sign-on, cas

I've been trying to install the latest version of CAS and in the overlay war in the /WEB-INF/ directory, there is no web.xml.

Even in the pom its explicitly mentioned that it should not fail when it's built with the property failOnMissingWebXml=false.

I can't figure out how else am I supposed to, you know, run the war! There is no web.xml!

How is anyone else not facing this issue while running Apereo CAS!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "spring-boot:run" command to run

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with the sample overlay: https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template?